# How can I log in to Starcraft 2 automatically?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make StarCraft 2 remember my battle.net password?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6656/is-there-a-way-to-make-starcraft-2-remember-my-battle-net-password)

When I start Starcraft 2, it always prompts me to log in. I can save my username, but I still have to type in my password each time. How can I get it to skip this step and log me in automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Blizzard does this as a security measure, and the minor inconvenience is worth knowing you're less likely to be hacked. Hackers could just steal the cookies off of your computer.

I even use an authenticator each time I log in to make sure nobody gets on my account but me.

Comment: Whether it's worth it is an individual decision. For me it is not. But if Blizzard does not allow it then I guess I have to live with it.

Comment: If you have a long password you can always change it to something shorter. That's what I did.